# Update HTML based on value of range slider

Tags: javascript

I am trying to output an HTML string based on the value of two range sliders, where each value 0-10 represent a distinct value.

I found this tutorial (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp) on sliders which includes javascript output to HTML but I cannot seem to get it to work with my customization.

Here is what I got, but it won't update the output:

```
<input id="a" type="range" min="1" max="10" value="1" onchange="UpdateText()"><br />
<input id="b" type="range" min="1" max="10" value="10" onchange="UpdateText()"><br />
Values: <span id="text"></span>

<script>
  // change b when a is adjusted
  document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    document.getElementById('b').value = 10 - (e.target.value - 1)
  })

  // change a when b is adjusted
  document.getElementById('b').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    document.getElementById('a').value = 10 - (e.target.value - 1)
  })

  var slidea = document.getElementById("a");
  var slideb = document.getElementById("b");
  var output = document.getElementById("text");

  output.innerHTML = "The first value is A, the second is J."; // Display the default slider value

  // Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
  function UpdateText() {

    switch(slidea.value) {
      case 1:
        var adisplay = "A";
        break;
      case 2:
        var adisplay = "B";
        break;
      case 3:
        var adisplay = "C";
        break;
      case 4:
        var adisplay = "D";
        break;
      case 5:
        var adisplay = "E";
        break;
      case 6:
        var adisplay = "F";
        break;
      case 7:
        var adisplay = "G";
        break;
      case 8:
        var adisplay = "H";
        break;
      case 9:
        var adisplay = "I";
        break;
      case 10:
        var adisplay = "J";
        break;
      default:
    }     

    switch(slideb.value) {
      case 1:
        var bdisplay = "A";
        break;
      case 2:
        var bdisplay = "B";
        break;
      case 3:
        var bdisplay = "C";
        break;
      case 4:
        var bdisplay = "D";
        break;
      case 5:
        var bdisplay = "E";
        break;
      case 6:
        var bdisplay = "F";
        break;
      case 7:
        var bdisplay = "G";
        break;
      case 8:
        var bdisplay = "H";
        break;
      case 9:
        var bdisplay = "I";
        break;
      case 10:
        var bdisplay = "J";
        break;
      default:
    }   

    output.innerHTML = "The first value is " + adisplay.value + ", the second is " + bdisplay.value + ".";

  } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look, I have change the syntax in simple way.

```js
//Get reference to sliders(A & B)
const sliderA = document.getElementById('a');
const sliderB = document.getElementById('b');
//Get reference to outputs(A & B)
const outputA = document.getElementById('outputA');
const outputB = document.getElementById('outputB');
//Store alphabets in array
const myDisplayValue = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'];

//On slider change invoke respective function
sliderA.addEventListener('change', handleSliderA);
sliderB.addEventListener('change', handleSliderB);


function handleSliderA() {
 //Get the alphabet from array based on slider value
  //Note: Array is Zero(0) based
 outputA.innerText = myDisplayValue[sliderA.value - 1];
}

function handleSliderB() {
 //Get the alphabet from array based on slider value
  //Note: Array is Zero(0) based
 outputB.innerText = myDisplayValue[sliderB.value - 1];
}
```

```html
<input id="a" type="range" min="1" max="10" value="1"><br />
<input id="b" type="range" min="1" max="10" value="10"><br />
Values: The first value is <span id="outputA">A</span>, the second is <span id="outputB">J</span>
```

Comment: Not only fixed the problem but agreed a much cleaner way than I had. Had to make a few slight changes to add back in the functionality to adjust the opposite slider but wasn't too difficult.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 errors. 
1rst:
In every case you should add "", example

```
case "1":
        var adisplay = "A";
        break;
```

2nd:

When you display the result, you should add "value" to the var, because it's a var, not an input. 
Correct way:

```
output.innerHTML = "The first value is " + adisplay+ ", the second is " + bdisplay+ ".";
```

I recomend you to don't declare your vars every case.

Comment: This solution is good but incomplete : declaring variables inside the `switch` statement will make them inaccessible outside the `switch`. But I have missed the quotations around the numbers, so we're even :)

Comment: Actually, declaring the variables inside the switch works fine. Especially when using var. because var is function scope rather than block scoped.

Comment: @Zachary Haber I have tested it in Firefox and I get a `TypeError: adisplay is undefined`; does it work in your browser?

Comment: @Invizio, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62056178/13175138 take a look. It still uses the vars in there. The issue would be due to the default case being reached which doesn't instantiate the variable.

Comment: Alright, I found the problem. You are right, `adisplay is undefined` only means it didn't enter any case of the switch, hence my misunderstanding. Looks this this answer is the correct one. My bad, and have my +1!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** : Added a third mistake, thanks to @Sarai Lopez's answer.

I found <strike>two</strike> *three* errors in your code snippet.

I ran your code in a sample document, looked at the console (hit F12 on your keyboard while looking at your document), and found this error :

```
TypeError: adisplay is undefined
```

The error means that **you didn't declare your variable in the correct [scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)**. That means that once the code exits the `switch` statement, your variable is no longer accessible.

To fix the error, simply :

1. Declare `adisplay` and `bdisplay` at the beginning of your function, and remove the `var`'s in front of your assignments to prevent redectaration (which would lead to another error).

```
function UpdateText() {
    // Here
    var adisplay;
    var bdisplay;
    ...
        // Inside your switch statement - remove the "var"
        adisplay = "A";
    ...
}
```

2. The other mistake I've seen is the following : in Javascript, you don't need to type `.value` to access the value of your variable. Simply use this line instead :

```
output.innerHTML = "The first value is " + adisplay + ", the second is " + bdisplay + ".";
```

3. You need to put quotes around the numbers in your `case` :

```
switch(...) {
case "1": // Here
    ...
}
```

With these <strike>two</strike> *three* fixes, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you write

```
var adisplay = ""
```

in the switch statement, you are declaring a new variable. Try taking those all out and it should work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are getting at. I have to choose what text to use based on the value of the slider.

Answer (score 0):

So, your main errors in UpdateText are that the input's values are a string rather than a number. So I cast it to a number using `+slidea.value`

The other error is that you don't need to use `.value` on a variable that isn't an object with a value property. e.g. use `adisplay` instead of `adisplay.value` which was throwing an error because it was undefined due to the bug mentioned above.

Outside of that, I moved the UpdateText() calls into the `addEventListener`s because they were running in the wrong order otherwise. You'd want to set the other input before updating the text, otherwise the text is always going to be one update behind.

As mentioned elsewhere, you should also move your var declarations in the switch statement to outside it because you could end up with undefined variables if the default case is reached.

```js
var slidea = document.getElementById("a");
var slideb = document.getElementById("b");
var output = document.getElementById("text");

// change b when a is adjusted
slidea.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  slideb.value = 10 - (e.currentTarget.value - 1)
  UpdateText();
})

// change a when b is adjusted
slideb.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  slidea.value = 10 - (e.currentTarget.value - 1)
  UpdateText();
})


output.innerHTML = "The first value is A, the second is J.";; // Display the default slider value

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
function UpdateText() {
  switch (+slidea.value) {
    case 1:
      var adisplay = "A";
      break;
    case 2:
      var adisplay = "B";
      break;
    case 3:
      var adisplay = "C";
      break;
    case 4:
      var adisplay = "D";
      break;
    case 5:
      var adisplay = "E";
      break;
    case 6:
      var adisplay = "F";
      break;
    case 7:
      var adisplay = "G";
      break;
    case 8:
      var adisplay = "H";
      break;
    case 9:
      var adisplay = "I";
      break;
    case 10:
      var adisplay = "J";
      break;
    default:
  }
  switch (+slideb.value) {
    case 1:
      var bdisplay = "A";
      break;
    case 2:
      var bdisplay = "B";
      break;
    case 3:
      var bdisplay = "C";
      break;
    case 4:
      var bdisplay = "D";
      break;
    case 5:
      var bdisplay = "E";
      break;
    case 6:
      var bdisplay = "F";
      break;
    case 7:
      var bdisplay = "G";
      break;
    case 8:
      var bdisplay = "H";
      break;
    case 9:
      var bdisplay = "I";
      break;
    case 10:
      var bdisplay = "J";
      break;
    default:
  }

  output.innerHTML = "The first value is " + adisplay + ", the second is " + bdisplay + ".";

}
```

```html
<input id="a" type="range" min="1" max="10" value="1"><br />
<input id="b" type="range" min="1" max="10" value="10"><br /> Values: <span id="text"></span>
```